# indexPathForObject returns nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am passing an object from my UITableViewController to a singleton, then back to my UITableViewController through a notification. The UITableViewController uses a NSFetchedResultsController. It then want the indexPath of the Object in the fetchedResultsController.

```
Object *obj = (Object *)notification.object;
NSIndexPath *index = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:obj];
```

I set the notification in the AFNetworking/AFDownloadRequestOperation progress block:

```
- (void)downloadObject:(Object *)object
{
........

    [operation1 setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
                         ////// Sending Notification
                         ////// Try to send notification only on significant download
                         totalBytesRead = ((totalBytesRead *100)/totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile);
                         NSLog(@"TOTAL BYTES IN PROGRESS BLOCK: %llu",totalBytesRead);
                         NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                         [userDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:totalBytesRead] forKey:@"progress"];
                         [userDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile] forKey:@"totalBytes"];
                         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DownloadProgress%@",object.uniqueID] object:object userInfo:userDictionary];
}
```

There is only one object in `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];` and it matches the object the passed back in the notification. The `index` is always nil, but the fetchedResultsController is not nil, and the `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` returns the correct object. Why does `indexPathForObject` nil?

Comment: I dont know but the way you transfer data sound **HORRIBLE**. Anyway: have you tried using the `indexOfObject:` method int the `fetchedObjects` property just so check for sure. If that still return nil, then your code is doing something wrong and the objects *are* different.

Comment: Why does it sound horrible? I have my singleton send a notification that my other classes listen for to update a download progress on my UITableViewCells. This updates all my views in my TabBar, where using a delegate did not update across my app. Is there a better way? I will check if the objects are the same that way

Comment: Singleton is almost everytime bad, should be avoided at pretty much any cost. Maybe use said delegation or the strongly by Objective-C suppored KVO. But sending data from A to B to C just to get it back to A does not sound like a strong design.

Comment: Show how you post the notification.

Comment: Added code that posts the notification.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In the configuration of my `NSFetchedResultsController` the `sectionNameKeyPath` was set to refer to an (optional) related object.
It turned out that this relation must be fulfilled (that is the related object must not be nil).
After ensuring, that every relation of the `sectionNameKeyPath` is fulfilled, the `indexPathForObject` method worked again as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are attempting to locate an object in a table view from the notification object...

You should be calling the index path method on your table view object, not your notification object.

Try matching your local variable:

```
Object *obj = (Object *)notification.object;
```

with:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

(if it is the only one that should be relatively easy)...

```
NSArray *arrayFetchedObjects = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
Object *tableObject = [arrayObjects lastObject];
```

(if there is more than one then you might need to filter the `arrayFetchedObjects` but that is another question)

then locating the position of that fetched object in the table view:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:tableObject];
```

Comment: That did not fix it. I figured out the problem, and it was related to my section sort. The index of the object was nil, because it was placed in an unnamed section. I did not see the errors until I started messing with the sorts.